# Report with a wrong Territory View

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, territory, hierarchy

I created

1. a **custom Report Type** "O-p-p".
2. A report X with the "O-p-p" custom Report Type.

When I build the report I cannot see any row, because it is set with a certain territory point of view in the **Territory Hierarchy**.

The problem is that I have never set the "Territory Hierarchy" in the phases 1 and 2. How can I create the report with the classic **Role Hierarchy**?

In addition: in the report (no filters on it) it results 10000 opportunities, while in the workbench it results 14000 opportunities (more or less).